# Is there a Linux system call to open a deivce file thru its major/minor numbers?

Tags: linux, system-calls

Traditionally, I have to open a device file using `open()` system call, which takes a `char*` argument pointing to the path of the device file, such as `/dev/ttyS0`.

It then reads the file for only two numbers, the major and minor numbers, and then open the device for me.

If I already know the major/minor numbers, can I directly open the device? i.e. Is there a "open" system call returns a file descriptor, but takes two arguments, the major and the minor numbers?

I don't want to waste time on reading the file system, in a mission critical application.

Comment: The device id has no relation to the actual filename of any special files created via `mknod` using those numbers, unless whatever does create them uses a consistent naming scheme.

Comment: No, I don't think there's any such call, it would be a security violation. What if the device special file is in a directory you don't have permission to access? In particular, if you're in a chroot jail, it would allow you to open devices outside the jail.

Comment: It's the same reason you can't open regular files by specifying the inode number.